# Was trying to make an spinner dependent on another spinner with an intent..But where do i introduce intent and to pass a value with it?

Tags: android

here is the code

```
public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                                   long id) {
            final int p = pos;
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            if (pos==0){
                choosePersonalPlan();
            }else if (pos==1){
                chooseLargeBusPlan();
            } else if (pos==2){
                chooseSmallMedPlan();
            }


            /*Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent("com.example.android.testing.SecondActivity"));
             //intent.putExtra("value",str);
            //---set the data to pass back---
            //data.setData(Uri.parse(str));
            //setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            //---closes the activity---
            //finish();
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }




        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

need to pass the value of the pos in the onItemSelected method using intent to the next activity which is SecondActivity?
how can i do this please tell me!!
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Call second activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("selected_plan", spPlan.getSelectedItemPosition());
startActivity(i);
```

and you can access plan from second activity.

```
int selectedPlan = getIntent().getIntExtra("selected_plan");
```